# How to provide iOS app to a tester whose uuid is not available

Tags: ios, testflight

- I built an app and now I want it to give to a tester
- I did setup a testflight account for me and my devices
- However, I dont have the UUID of tester and he is remote.
- I think testflight needs UUID of device.

Is there a way I can get the app installed on his device?

Can I create a download link from where **anyone** can download??

Comment: If it's a regular developer account, you will need the UDID. Otherwise, you would need a Developer Enterprise Account ($299/year) in order to distribute In-House (unlimited devices, no UDID required). See this: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: As per Apple: "TestFlight Beta Testing makes it easy to invite users to test your iOS 8 apps before you release them on the App Store. You can invite up to 1,000 external testers using just their email address."

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using testflightapp.com, I'd suggest not using that and utilize the iTunes connect method as Apple will be shutting the site down soon.

Regarding UUIDs in iTunesConnect; You shouldn't need to.  All you need is to add them as an external user (that is if they are not an itunesconnect user) and send your app through the beta review process.

When you invite them, they will get an email to prompt them to download the test flight app which will do all the magic of installing the app.